# ncks: ERROR received 3 filenames; need no more than two

Tags: python, netcdf, cdo-climate, nco, ncks

I have six CSV files which I have sent in this link (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GQtyY1mI1YrK8GFP9SEo7dZfFHexKro3?usp=sharing). Each of these files has 720 rows and 360 columns which indicates longitude and latitude respectively. The first point of latitude is -89.75, the first point of longitude is -179.75, and the resolution of these data is 0.5 degrees. I want to convert them to a NetCDF file, so my code is this:

```
cdo -f nc -setreftime,1900-01-01,00:00:00,1day \
          -settaxis,1901-01-01,12:00:00,1day \
          -setcalendar,standard \
          -input,gridfile.txt \
          1901_1.nc < CSV_TO_nc/1901_1.csv

cdo -f nc -setreftime,1900-01-01,00:00:00,1day \
          -settaxis,1901-01-02,12:00:00,1day \
          -setcalendar,standard \
          -input,gridfile.txt \
          1901_2.nc < CSV_TO_nc/1901_2.csv

cdo -f nc -setreftime,1900-01-01,00:00:00,1day \
          -settaxis,1901-01-03,12:00:00,1day \
          -setcalendar,standard \
          -input,gridfile.txt \
          1901_3.nc < CSV_TO_nc/1901_3.csv

...

cdo -O -chname,var1,tmp \
       -setattribute,var1@long_name='monthly mean temperature',var1@units='degrees Celsius' \
       -mergetime \
       1901_*.nc 1901.nc

ncpdq -O -a lon,lat,time 1901.nc tmp.nc

ncks -O --fix_rec_dmn lon tmp.nc 1901reorder.nc

and the gridfile.txt is:

gridtype = lonlat

gridsize = 259200

xname = lon

xlongname = longitude

xunits = degrees_east

yname = lat

ylongname = latitude

yunits = degrees_north

xsize = 720

ysize = 360

xfirst = -179.75

xinc = 0.5

yfirst = -89.75

yinc = 0.5
```

unfortunately, I have the following error:

```
ncks: ERROR received 3 filenames; need no more than two
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

The NCO documentation [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#fix_rec_dmn) explains the most probable reason (an old version of NCO, < 4.2.5) why you received that message from `ncks`. The solution would be to upgrade and use the same command, or to continue using an ancient NCO by eliminating the `lon` argument thusly:

```
ncks -O --fix_rec_dmn tmp.nc 1901reorder.nc # NCO < 4.2.5
ncks -O --fix_rec_dmn lon tmp.nc 1901reorder.nc # NCO >= 4.2.5
```

Comment: you mean I should upgrade my NCO?

Comment: or drop the 'lon' argument as newly clarified above

Comment: when I eliminate the 'lon' (ncks -O --fix_rec_dmn tmp.nc 1901reorder.nc), I have the following error:                              
 nco_err_exit(): ERROR Short NCO-generated message (usually name of function that triggered error): nco_inq_dimlen()
nco_err_exit(): ERROR Error code is -46. Translation into English with nc_strerror(-46) is "NetCDF: Invalid dimension ID or name"
nco_err_exit(): ERROR NCO will now exit with system call exit(EXIT_FAILURE)

Comment: How can I upgrade my nco in windows? The version of my nco is 4.2.0

Comment: Install Conda, then NCO

Comment: It does not matter which version of NCO I install?

Comment: It matters. Install must be >= 4.2.5. I recommend the latest, 4.9.7.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have installed 4.9.5 and I do not have that error any more.